# Generate JSON with MySQL and PHP for dynamic d3.js lib

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I'm working with Laravel on a client project and I want to set up a tree structure with users registered in the system. I found a script from the d3.js library that performs the task, and for that it uses JSONs to get the data.

The structure it works on is as follows:

```
{
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [{
            "name": "Level 2: A",
            "parent": "Top Level",
            "children": [{
                    "name": "Son of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Daughter of A",
                    "parent": "Level 2: A"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Level 2: B",
            "parent": "Top Level"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried to prepare my JSON in the same format, but I couldn't manage. I have a user in my database, for example, that has `"parent": null` in my case: `"id_user_parent": null`, and all other users are related to other user IDs.

My question is, how to leave this user that `"id_user_parent": null` first and the others are populated with their respective children?

My call in my controller:

```
$users = User::select('name_first', 'name_second', 'id_user_parent')->get()
```

And the answer from my database is:

```
[
    {
        "name_first": "Tiago",
        "name_second": "Revers Paza",
        "id_user_parent": null
    }, 
    {
        "name_first": "Yuri",
        "name_second": "Luiz Hugo da Cunha",
        "id_user_parent": 1
    }, 
    {
        "name_first": "Severino",
        "name_second": "Ben\u00edcio das Neves",
        "id_user_parent": 1
    }
]
```

I generated a script and treated this data from the database and got the following result:

```
$users = User::select('name_first', 'name_second', 'id_user_parent')->get();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    if ($user['id_user_parent'] == null) {
        $main['name'] = $user['name_first'] . ' ' . $user['name_second'];
        $main['parent'] = $user['id_user_parent'];

        $data = $main;
    }
}
foreach($users as $key => $user) {
    if ($user['id_user_parent'] != null) {
        $data['children'][$key]['name'] = $user['name_first'] . ' ' . $user['name_second'];
        $data['children'][$key]['parent'] = $user['id_user_parent'];
    }
}
dd($data);
```

And my JSON result is:

```
array:3 [▼
    "name" => "Tiago Revers Paza"
    "parent" => null
    "children" => array:2 [▼
        1 => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Yuri Luiz Hugo da Cunha"
            "parent" => 1
        ]
        2 => array:2 [▼
            "name" => "Severino Benício das Neves"
            "parent" => 1
        ]
    ]
]
```

That is, as it is "expected" but, it only works with a single level and the idea is to relate according to `id_user_parent`.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to generate this JSON dynamically coming from my database?